# jsreport excel xml attribute Format ISO-8601 date to custom `d-mmm-yy`

Tags: excel, xml, jsreport

### Any idea how to format ISO-8601 date to custom `d-mmm-yy` ?

I'm struggling to format date from ISO-8601 to custom `numFmtId=15` cell.
From my searching I found:

- [OpenXml and Date format in Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033376/openxml-and-date-format-in-excel-cell), [What do excel xml cell attribute values mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334314/what-do-excel-xml-cell-attribute-values-mean), [What's the difference between <c t="str"> and <c><is> in Office Open XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740179/whats-the-difference-between-c-t-str-and-cis-in-office-open-xml) give me headstart on understanding excel xml.
- [Microsoft docs 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc880130(v=office.14)) which suggest `<x:xf>` and `<cellStyleXfs>`, [Microsoft docs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee859234(v=office.14)) explaining about `numFmts (Number Formats)` which I haven't found how it's supposed to works in cell format.
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c02fc9f9-0a7d-40b5-ac16-48199df474ba/spreadsheet-format-number?forum=oxmlsdk which suggest to make two different excel with the second being what you expected and compare the `.xml` the only difference I found was only in `styles.xml` which suggest `numFmtId="15"`
- http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/dates-in-strict-spreadsheetml-files/
- http://officeopenxml.com/SScontentOverview.php
- [Applying number formatting in OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501843/applying-number-formatting-in-openxml)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9c5d65f6-46d7-4767-be3f-24862dff4a78/open-xml-spreadsheet-style-error?forum=oxmlsdk
- [What indicates an Office Open XML Cell contains a Date/Time value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730152/what-indicates-an-office-open-xml-cell-contains-a-date-time-value)

I was able to detect whether or not the column header that contains `date` keyword and whatever column value inside, but I was unable to format it properly.

The best I was able to found on jsreport related thread was: https://jsreport.net/learn/html-to-xlsx which wasn't helping me that much since I was using `xlsx` recipe.

**You can see <kbd>[playground](https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/1FlBlKfb)</kbd> here which contains my progress so far.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format cell you can add on `style.xml`:

```
  `<xf numFmtId="15" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="1" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1" applyFill="1" applyBorder="1" applyAlignment="1">
     <alignment horizontal="center" />
  </xf>`
```

And update which part which using that format.
example:
`<c t="d" s="4">`

You can see result on <kbd>[Playground](https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/maYvTbXc)</kbd>  here.

The most helpful resources from which I've linked in the question:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c02fc9f9-0a7d-40b5-ac16-48199df474ba/spreadsheet-format-number?forum=oxmlsdk help me a lot comparing the `.xml` to find the difference to add.
- [What do excel xml cell attribute values mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334314/what-do-excel-xml-cell-attribute-values-mean) explaining what attributes do.